# Leg Muscle pain while running on treadmill

Tags: running, treadmill, foot-pain

My **Fibularis Longus muscle** pains when I run on treadmill or even on ground.
Even with a less speed on starting running immediately this muscle starts paining. 
Initially I thought it would recover by the time as I was new with running, But its more then 3 months now but still pain is intact. 
Please suggest me what should I do? Stop Running?

Comment: You've probably got inflammation.  You should have it checked by a physician.

Comment: Given that there are multiple muscles running the same direction in the lower leg, how can you pinpoint it to the peroneus longus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. When I start running and start to feel pain I decrease my speed and focus on my running form. If the pain doesn't stop after 1000-2000 meters I simply stop running.
2. Probably you don't do the warming up the way you need to. Check for some foam roller exercise. You can do them with big glass bottle like wine one too.
3. You should go and see physician now and he/she will advice you what to do, but generally you should listen to your body. There were times I have been allowed to run, but my body have told me it need more time after I tore something around my knee. So this is my advice - listen to your body and respond accordingly.
4. If you aren't allowed to run, check for other exercises. You should keep doing something to stay fit.  I really recommend swimming.